# How to programmatically scroll an HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have an `HorizontalScrollView` which contains a `RelativeLayout`. This layout is empty in the XML, and is populated from java in the onCreate.

I would like this scroll view to be initially somewhere in the middle of the `RelativeLayout`, which is way larger than the screen.

I tried `mHorizScrollView.scrollTo(offsetX, 0);` which doesn't work.
I don't know what's wrong with this.

I could post the code, but it is not really relevant. What matters is that everything is done programatically (has to :s), and that the initial position of the `HorizontalScrollView` has to be set programmatically.

Thanks for reading. Please tell me if you need more details or if this is not clear enough.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found that if you `extend` the `HorizontalScrollView` and override the `onLayout`, you can cleanly scroll, after the super call to `onLayout`:

```
MyScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {
    protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        this.scrollTo(wherever, 0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
For scrolling to *start* or *end* you can use:

```
this.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT/FOCUS_LEFT);
```

instead of

```
this.scrollTo(wherever, 0);
```

Answer (score 26):

```
public void autoSmoothScroll() {

        final HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.horiscroll);
        hsv.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //hsv.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                hsv.smoothScrollBy(500, 0);
            }
        },100);
    }
```

Comment: I want to scroll to a view in horizontal scroll view. This code works for me. I used `hsv.post()` instead of `hsv.postDelayed()`

Comment: this is also good to scroll smoothly 
   hsv.arrowScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_LEFT/RIGHT);

Answer (score 16):

To test whether it's a timing issue (which I think it is), instead of calling scrollTo() in onStart, call postDelayed() with a Runnable that calls scrollTo, with a delay of 30 or so.

Comment: This confirmed that it is, indeed, a timing issue. Is there a cleaner way to do this, than a postDelayed Runnable ?

Comment: You could probably subclass HorizontalScrollView, add a field that indicates that scrolling is necessary, and then do the scrolling at the end of the next call to onLayout() (or perhaps on computeScroll() or some other method). I think using postDelayed is just easier.

Comment: I found something curious, i think with 'scroll.smoothScrollTo' you need more delay then with 'scroll.scrollTo'.

Comment: I would be very careful using delays as a solution as you can't say if the delay set on your device/emulator will fit the performance of every other device. I think the better and cleaner solution is extending HorizontalScrollView as you can see in HaIR's answer

Comment: @Muzikant - I think HaIR's answer offers a better solution than my own.

Answer (score 9):

A better approach would be using the `ViewTreeObserver` to observe layouts.

```
View interestedInView;
onCreate(){
  //Code

  //Observe for a layout change
  ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = interestedInView.getViewTreeObserver();
  if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        //REMOVE THE VIEWTREE OBSERVER
        //interestedInView is ready for size and position queries because it has been laid out
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help its working for me, but I have question does it require more processing then  postdelayed(new Runnable() ....)

Comment: Well, if you are taking run-time overhead, the answer is yes, because you are adding a new listener and removing it then. But it is so very minimal that it wont count. And it's worth the robustness of the approach.

Comment: Now I am using ViewTreeObserver and its working for me, please tell me if its less efficient or what ???

Comment: @MGD Not really. You are only attaching a listener and then removing it. So its equally efficient and more importantly, very robust.

Comment: thanks for the comment Vikram yet I am having lil problem that I have posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414035/horizontal-scrollview-full-scroll-focus-right-with-viewtreeobserver please consider this question if you could help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the view doesn't have a size yet. The Clean way to do this is to implement the onSizeChanged of the ScrollView to send a message to a Handler in your activity to in order to notify the activity that the view has a size and that scrolling is possible.

Comment: This looked really good but it doesn't work. I created a class that extends HorizontalScrollView, and that implements onSizeChanged. When this callback is called, it calls a method in the activity that does the scrolling.
However, the scroll is not working. It only works if it is post delayed.

Answer (score 1):

Use view.post and write scrollTo(x,y) inside run method. This the way to invalidate view in post method as per android API document.

Comment: I just replaced my postDelayed with a .post and it works like a charm. Just as robust as a listener as it is triggered _after_ the view has bee attached.
I use this to access the dimensions of a view as this is only available after it has been attached to the screen an measured.

Answer (score 1):

Use Kotlin extension function.

```
inline fun <T : View> T.afterMeasured(crossinline f: T.() -> Unit) {
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        if (measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0) {
            viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            f()
        }
    }
})
```

}

Usage:

```
mHorizontalScrollView.afterMeasured {
        var scrollTo = 0
        val count = (layout.svList.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout)
            .childCount

        if(index < count){
            val child = (layout.svList.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout)
                .getChildAt(index)

            scrollTo = child.width

        }

        Log.d(TAG, "scrollToComment: $scrollTo")

        mHorizontalScrollView.scrollTo(scrollTo, 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The scrollTo function should work. What is the layout_width of the HSV, and the view inside of it?

Comment: I think this is a timing issue. The views inside the HSV are added at runtime (from onCreate) and the layout_width of the HSV is fill_parent. The mHSV.scrollTo() is called from onStart.

Answer (score 0):

The onSizeChanged function should work. What you fail to understand is that the onSizeChanged should send a message to a Handler of your activity and not any callback function, because a handler will execute code in the UI thread. You cannot do UI operations outside it. Have a look at handlers.

Comment: onSizeChanged must be called in the UI thread because when I called the scrollTo from onSizeChanged, it did not complain.