# Android, make scrollable view overflow to the left instead of right?

Tags: java, android

I was recommended using a parent view to get horizontal scrolling right in my TextView:

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:text="123456789"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Horizontal scrolling works fine but it makes the content overflow to the right when it gets longer than it's parent's width:

```
-------
|123456|7
-------
```

However I'm working on a textview that holds numbers and since numbers are commonly aligned to the right I need the textview to overflow to the opposite side. (you should have to scroll left to see the beginning of the string).

```
 ------
1|4567|
 ------
```

I have tried multiple combinations of gravity="right" and widths but I cannot manage to do it. How can I align the text to the right and make it overflow to the left?

---

EDIT:

I tried doing this when the user types:

```
calc.setText( newNumber );
HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsv);
hsv.scrollTo(hsv.getRight(), hsv.getTop());
```

This scrolls to the right every time the user types a number, however the latest number is always left out of the screen (it's like it scrolled and THEN added the number).

Comment: Doubt: Where is your container layout for scroll-view??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the code . So there are two ways to get around this problem 
First one with ScrollBars

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){   
@Override
public void run() {
    HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsv1);
        hsv.scrollTo(hsv.getRight(), hsv.getTop());
    }       

},100L);
```

Second one is without scrollBars

```
 <TextView 
 android:ellipsize="start"   //add this line
 ...
 />
```

Comment: as you pointed out the only way to get around this is to delay the scrolling. Change content > wait 1 ms > scroll to the right. Btw I don't think the option with the TextView would work, it will only add `...` before the text but you won't be able to scroll. Or will you? It seems a more simple solution but I've used ellipsie before and I don't think it only adds the three dots

Comment: In case you remove the scrollbars and use ellipsize="start" following shall happen :
actual text: "12345667"
displayed text: "...45667" 
So the overflow shall be on left to show only the last part so as to fit the text in display.(Though it won't be scrollable)

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9507988/347565)

You can make your own class derived from HorizontalScrollView

```
public class RightAlignedHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {
    public RightAlignedHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RightAlignedHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RightAlignedHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        scrollTo(getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth(), 0);
    }
}
```

I posted a complete simple project [there](https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/right_aligned_horizontalscrollview)

Answer (score 1):

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/hsv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:text="123456789"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Added id to the HorizontalScrollView

```
HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsv1);
hsv.scrollTo(hsv.getRight(), hsv.getTop());
```

This is untested as I made it on the fly. Tell me how it goes.

Comment: I added the ID, pasted the code inside the activity codeblock and I imported HorizontalScrollView but I get various syntax error notes in the second line. Should I have added the code somewhere else?

Comment: @Liso22 What syntax errors? The `hsv.scrollTo(int, int)` can be called wherever, but if you want to start hsv all the way to the right, use it in `onCreate(Bundle)`

Comment: I just checked and found out it only works partially. Here's the problem if I do `calc.setText("12345")` and then immediatelly run your code, it scrolls to the right but it doesn't use the correct width. It doesn't take into account the changes I had done to the textview. So if I type 12345, I actually end up width 1234 on screen. (The 5 is left out)

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use `android:fillViewport="true"` property for scroll-view
[Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2034666/1450401) & [This](http://tech.chitgoks.com/tag/androidfillviewport/)

[Go through a Tutorial](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

```
   <ScrollView 
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"/>
```

Doubt: Where is your container layout for scroll-view??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try assigning the ellipsize parameter to your textview?

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="start"
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

For setting the gravity of the text when not overflowing, try setting

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this , this would work properly  and will not give you any delays when you jump between threads

```
hor = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
    hor.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            hor.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
        }
    }, 1L);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late at this, but here's a simple and easy approach by using rotation of the views.

```
horizontal_layout_id.setRotationY(180f)
```

The above code inverts the whole horizontal layout horizontally, this make the text start on the right instead of left. HOWEVER, this also inverts the text in the `textview` inside, which is obviously not good.

```
textview_inside_horizontal_layout_id.setRotationY(180f)
```

So, we invert the textview itself once more, this will mirror the mirrored text again! So, you'll end up having something like this-

[image]

This will make the text overflow to the right instead of left as well!